# HTML: protecting a site with multiple htaccess files

Tags: html, .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap

I have a (Bootstrap) site with top-level htaccess/htpasswd protection. This works fine, but I'd now like to add a new menu item, which requires a different (administrator) password.

My plan A is to have the new administrator menu show a single 'login' item. When you click on the login item, a page from the admin directory is loaded. The admin directory contains a second `.htaccess`, which currently contains

```
<Limit GET>
require user admin
</Limit>
```

However, this doesn't work, for at least 2 reasons:

(1) If the user originally logged in as `foo`, for example, and then clicks the login menu item, Apache doesn't offer to let the user log in again as `admin` - the error log simply says

```
access to /foo/admin/admin.html failed, reason: user 'foo' does not meet 'require'ments for user/valid-user to be allowed access
```

Is there some way to force the password dialog to appear?

(2) My top-level `index.html` currently does a virtual include of the admin page:

```
<div id="siteAdminDiv" class="container" style="display:none">
  <!--#include virtual="admin/admin.html" -->
</div>
```

this doesn't work (unsurprisingly), since Apache tries to load the page on the initial site load, and the load fails because the user has just entered a user-level rather than an admin password. Any idea how I load this page only when it's required, in such a way that it doesn't redirect, for example, and fits into the existing Bootstrap structure?

Thanks.